# navigating links in a web page and searching words using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From main page of a website "http://myWebPage.com", I need to find all the links to pages and sub pages and finally  count the occurrence of certain words/terms from each page.

**My Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://myWebPage.com"))
#searching all the links matching "https:/solutions/blah-blah-blah-
#blah.html"
tags = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/solutions/......html")
# write all the links to a notepad and go to those link and search for the 
#terms
f = open('test.txt', 'wt')`enter code here`
f.write(tags)
f.close()
```

Error:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's the mode `t`? The only authorized mode i know are `r`, `a`, `w`, `r+`

Comment: It is "wb"  which means that you are writing to the file (w), and that you are writing in binary mode (b).